# Ошибка при загрузке фикстур с использованием шифрования пароля

Tags: symfony2

Версия Symfony - 2.8

При загрузке фикстур сущности User с использованием шифрования пароля появляется ошибка:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>     Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to LoadUsersRolesData::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInt
>     erface, none given, called in /home/user/yandex/shop/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Loader.php on line 358 and defined

Делаю все согласно документации: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Код:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use App\ShopBundle\Entity\Role;
use App\ShopBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class LoadUsersRolesData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $role = new Role();
        $role->setName('ROLE_ADMIN');
        $role->setDescription('Учётная запись администратора');

        $manager->persist($role);

        $role2 = new Role();
        $role2->setName('ROLE_BUYER');
        $role2->setDescription('Учётная запись покупателя');

        $manager->persist($role2);

        //Добавление пользователя админа
        $user = new User();
        $user->setUserName('admin');
        $user->setEmail('admin@shop.my');

        $password = $this->encoder->encodePassword($user, 'admin');
        $user->setPassword($password);

        $user->getUserRoles()->add($role);

        $manager->persist($user);

        //Добавление пользователя покупателя
        $user2 = new User();
        $user2->setUserName('user');
        $user2->setEmail('user@shop.my');

        //Шифрование пароля
        $password = $this->encoder->encodePassword($user2, 'test');

        $user2->setPassword($password);
        $user2->getUserRoles()->add($role2);

        $manager->persist($user2);

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

В документации также написано, что можно сделать шифрование пароля через 
свойство $this->container, но хотелось бы узнать почему не работает именно так. Версия Symfony не подходит, м.б. вместо это другой класс надо использовать..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По вашей [ссылке на документацию](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) расположена документация к DoctrineFixturesBundle версии 3.0. Эта версия [требует](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/blob/master/composer.json#L24) Symfony 3.3 и новее, в которых появились автовайринг и авторегистрация. Ошибка, которую вы видите, собственно и означает, что в конструктор не пришло никаких аргументов.

Comment: Не могу сказать, практиковалась ли во времена Symfony 2.8 регистрация фикстур как сервисов, но если получится, можете сказать об этом в комментариях и я добавлю это в ответ. Или просто используйте контейнер как ServiceLocator.